# Facebook share return empty data even user logged in App

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm building application have function when use share on facebook they will get

point from this action. By check this, I will check if facebook response post_id

but it return empty for me event user logged in app like with scrope

"publish_actions". I searched around but I cant see any thing help? This is my

code

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log(response)
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            href: url_here,
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, { scope: 'publish_actions', return_scopes: true });
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your console say anything ?

Comment: It show empty array

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not allowed and not possible. You will never get `publish_actions` approved for this, because you must not reward users in any way for sharing something. You need to read the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> 4.5: Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

Answer (score -1):

I've just find the issue. I used old app Id that I build before. So I create new facebook app and point it to current website I'm building. It's work perfect

Thanks guys for rep

Comment: It’s still **spam**. You are not allowed to reward users for sharing in any way. Please read Platform Policy, and follow it.